# How can i load a bigquery table to dataproc cluster

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-dataproc

I am new to dataproc cluster and PySpark so, in the process of looking for codes to load table from bigquery to the cluster, i came across the code below and was unable to figure out what all am i suppose to change for my usecase in this code and what are we providing as an input in the input directory

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
import subprocess


sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)


bucket = spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.system.bucket')
project = spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.project.id')
input_directory = 'gs://{}/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_input'.format(bucket)


conf = {
    'mapred.bq.project.id': project,
    'mapred.bq.gcs.bucket': bucket,
    'mapred.bq.temp.gcs.path': input_directory,
    'mapred.bq.input.project.id': 'dataset_new',
    'mapred.bq.input.dataset.id': 'retail',
    'mapred.bq.input.table.id': 'market',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use [Hadoop BigQuery connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors), for Spark you should use [Spark BigQuery connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector).

To read data from BigQuery you can follow [an example](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example):

```py
# Use the Cloud Storage bucket for temporary BigQuery export data used
# by the connector.
bucket = "[bucket]"
spark.conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', bucket)

# Load data from BigQuery.
words = spark.read.format('bigquery') \
  .option('table', 'bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare') \
  .load()
words.createOrReplaceTempView('words')

# Perform word count.
word_count = spark.sql(
    'SELECT word, SUM(word_count) AS word_count FROM words GROUP BY word')
word_count.show()
```